# Python 3.6.5rc1. Nuitka. RuntimeError: Bad magic number in .pyc file

Tags: python, python-3.x, nuitka

Система : Debian.
Python : 3.6.5rc1
Компиляция с помощью Nuitka.

Вводимая команда для компиляции : `nuitka --python-version=3.6 python_script.py`

Появляется ошибка : `RuntimeError: Bad magic number in .pyc file`

Но при этом в этой же папке никаких .pyc файлов нет.

С чем связана проблема ?

Answer (score 1):

Для скриптов написанных с Python3 нужно использовать nuitka3.
Для скриптов написанных с Python2 нужно использовать nuitka.